# Angular ui-view (UI-Router) not rendering template - plunker included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

**Question Background:**

I am using AngulaJS's UI Router for the first time to create two views within my app.

**The Issue:**

***Plunker link:*** https://plnkr.co/edit/2XAKa6mDCUyzyOPz2CNK

I feel I'm missing something simple here but I cannot get any route to render the specified html templates set in the app.js.

Eventually I want the Update.html template to render when the submit fucntion of the home.html (search()) is clicked but first off I need to be able to actually render a single view which I currently cannot.

I would expect on-load for the route to render up the home.html page but it wont:

Any help sorting this will be much appreciated.

app.js:

```
 angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ])
  .config(['$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
      })
      .state('update', {
        url: '/update',
        templateUrl: 'Update.html',
        controller: 'UpdateController'
      })
  }])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your plunker briefly, it looks like your controller files are creating new angular apps with the same name. They were overriding each other so the `.config()` block didn't exist in the final app. I have updated the controller files in this plunker and it seems to be rendering the first ui view fine:

https://plnkr.co/edit/cdpWWOaBJWL3dONtIXzv?p=preview

Notice in the controller files, the `angular.module('app')` no longer has the second argument `['ui-bootstrap']` which was causing a new angular app to be created for each controller file. Check it out here in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).

> Beware that using angular.module('myModule', []) will create the module myModule and overwrite any existing module named myModule. Use angular.module('myModule') to retrieve an existing module.

Hope this helps!